# Error in catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm trying to use catkin _make in my catkin_workspace. I'm doing catkin_make in the root directory. But, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: File /home/ashikmh/catkin_ws/src/package.xml does not exist.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake:10 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:72 (stamp)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:50 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:99 (catkin_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (catkin_package)

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:116 (message):


catkin_package() 'catkin' must be listed as a buildtool dependency in the
  package.xml
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (catkin_package)
```

Why is the catkin_make searching for package.xml in the src directory of my workspace rather than my package? Is it any error in sourcing or any other issue. A good help is appreciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284282/error-in-catkin_make/) by [ashikmh14](https://answers.ros.org/users/33962/ashikmh14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-03**:
Welcome! Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of your `package.xml`?

**Comment by [ashikmh14](https://answers.ros.org/users/33962/ashikmh14/) on 2018-03-03**:
Hi jayess, Thank you for taking interest in the question. Fortunately I solved the issue. Actually I had somehow messed up with the toplevel.cmake .Which caused this problem, I reverted it to the default state and all went well !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding my question above, I had messed up with the toplevel.cmake somehow. Which is never to be done. This had caused my catkin_make to rather search for some unnecessary packages. Using a default toplevel.cmake from the web to replace the corrupted one can solve this issue. This has also been discussed in some earlier questions.

---

Originally posted by [ashikmh14](https://answers.ros.org/users/33962/ashikmh14/) with karma: 41 on 2018-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0